# jQuery slideshow cycle if

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slideshow

I asked a question on here a few days ago about an issue I was having with my jQuery image slider. The issue was fixed. But I am having issue with the slideshow cycling through the images. I am trying to create a if statement that will, if the user hits the back button when they are on the first image then it jumps to the last image, and if the user hits the forward button when they are on the last image it jumps to the first image.

This is the [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cpgkyjL2/)

This is the jQuery for the image slider, I have tried to create the if statement but, I just don't know where to start with it.

```
    $(".slideshow > div:last").show();
$(".left").click(function(){
var $active = $('.slideshow .active');
$('.active')
    .fadeOut(500)
    .removeClass('active')
    .prev()
    .addClass('active')
    .fadeIn(500);
```

});

```
$(".right").click(function(){
var $active = $('.slideshow .active');
$('.active')
    .fadeOut(500)
    .removeClass('active')
    .next()
    .addClass('active')
    .fadeIn(500);
    if(".slideshow > div:last") {
        $("");
    }
```

});

Thank you for anyhelp.

Comment: jsfiddle is not containing proper path to images also no library is attached. please update that

Comment: You might be looking for http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/demo/carousel.php